# Issue:  401 - Unauthorized: Access is Denied Due to Invalid Credentials

Tags: android, https, ntlm

In Android, I am trying to fetch data from the "HTTPS" site and this site used NTLM credentials , authentication, when I connect the site (client. execute) it gives a response:

> "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

I am setting UsernamePasswordCredentials, networkcredential, but the response remain same.

I have also follow the the instruction given at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html 
and 
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

but the response remain same.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i read a lot about it. But i have a "Answer" of how can you solve it.

The problem is HttpClient class because it doesnt support NTLM conecction, but, now the HttpClient api (4.2) can support it.

I read about it on Apache page, so you have to download the HttpClient 4.2 version and add it to your proyect. Use that HttpClient class and then shold works.

[You can download here:](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

I post it now because some people could found the solution here.